# Shortcut Microsoft Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity-3

We are trying to introduce Microsoft Authentication to our app using the ASP.NET 5 Web Application Template.

The default template takes the user from the login link in `_LoginPartial.cshtml` to the Login page where they select their preferred authentication provider. We only want to accept Microsoft authentication so we want `_LoginPartial.cshtml` to log the user in.

I have modified  `_LoginPartial.cshtml`

`<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        @*<li><a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">Register</a></li>*@
        <li><a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="ExternalLogin">Log in</a></li>
    </ul>`

I have also changed the provider parameter of `AccountController ExternalLogin`

```
        public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider="Microsoft", string returnUrl = null)
    {
        // Request a redirect to the external login provider.
        var redirectUrl = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, properties);
    }
```

But in my case  `ExternalLogin` is not called and a blank page

`http://localhost:52711/Account/ExternalLogin` is returned.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this one by replacing the login link button with a form

```
    <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="ExternalLogin" method="post" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" class="navbar-right">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link" name="provider" value="Microsoft" title="Log in">Log In</button>
</form>
```